# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH when accessing my asp.net web api on Raspberry PI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, raspberry-pi, console-application

I wrote a .NET Core 5 console app that, among other things, has a web API. When I run it on my Windows 10 computer, I can access the API from both a browser and Postman.

I installed it on a Raspberry PI running Raspberry PI OS. The console app runs and the API starts up. But when I try to browse to it from a browser or Postman, I get the error:

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

To create the API, I have the following code:

```
       public static IWebHost BuildWebHost( string[] args ) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder( args ).UseKestrel( options =>
        {
           options.Listen( IPAddress.Parse( args[ 0 ] ), int.Parse( args[ 1 ] ), listenOptions =>
           {
              listenOptions.UseHttps( MY_PFX_FILE, MY_CERT_PASS );
           } );
        } )

         .UseStartup<StartupApi>()
         .Build();
```

args[0] is currently the IP address to the computer running the API, and args[1] is the port.

Like I said, this works fine when its running in Windows. It fails only when it's running on the PI.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

It turned out to be the self-signed certificate I was using. It was a pfx we used for a version of the console app we ran on Windows. It wasn't working on the PI. I generated a new ss cert and it worked great.